# Friedman Rank Sum Test in R: Not an unreplicated complete block design

Tags: r, statistics

I run into an error trying to implement Friedman Rank Sum test on a dataframe. What is a likely cause of this error and how should I fix this?
[image]

Comment: Try naming your arguments, or put them in the correct order. Check the help page or type `args(stats:::friedman.test.default)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function call didn't include named arguments, which is a little dangerous at times.

Either put them in the correct order according to the order specified in the help page, which is:

`function (y, groups, blocks, ...)`:

```
friedman.test(new_frame$Detail, new_frame$brands, new_frame$factors)
```

or name them (you can keep your original order):

```
friedman.test(blocks=new_frame$factors, groups=new_frame$brands, y=new_frame$Detail)
```

or use the formula method:

```
friedman.test(Detail~brands|factors, data=new_frame)
```

All three versions should give you the same result. But I am not sure which variable is your block and which one is your group. I apologize if I have switched them.