# Quade/Friedman Test R requiring data for all group/block pairs

Tags: r

I have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21457505/friedman-test-unreplicated-complete-block-design-error), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49295109/error-in-friedman-test), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60598904/friedman-rank-sum-test-in-r-not-an-unreplicated-complete-block-design), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59866458/friedman-test-error-possibly-wrong-test) link, but it has not solved my problem yet.

Here is what I am working with. I have some survey responses where different raters responded on a Likert scale for different emotions.

```
Data = tibble(Emotion = c('Happy', 'Sad', 'Angry', 'Happy', 'Sad', 'Angry', 'Happy', 'Sad', 'Angry'), Rater = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), Likert = c(0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5))
```

This data frame has 9 observations, where each of the 3 raters rated each of the 3 observations with a Likert scale. If I want to run a Quade test on this using:

```
quade.test(Likert ~ Emotion | Rater, data = Data)
```

I am able to do so with no errors.

Now let's say I add the response for rater 4 into the mix:

```
Data = add_row(Data, Emotion = c('Happy'), Rater=c(4), Likert=c(3))
```

When I run the Quade test again with the same command as above, I get

```
Error in quade.test.default(c(0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 3), c("Happy",  : 
  not an unreplicated complete block design
```

But if I add the remaining two emotions with this, I do not get an error.

```
Data = add_row(Data, Emotion = c('Angry', 'Sad'), Rater=c(4, 4), Likert=c(3, 4))
```

Then when I add another row with a different emotion, I get the same error again

```
Data = add_row(Data, Emotion = c('Neutral'), Rater=c(4), Likert=c(3))
```

I do not have a value for each Emotion/Rater pair, which is what seems to be breaking this. Is there any work-around that someone could recommend?